# AngularJS $resource requests to Laravel - POST and PUT

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, laravel, angular-resource

I'm having a hard time with sending REST requests with `$resource` to Laravel application. First of all, `$resource` POST method sendes Request Payload, which I am unable to read in Laravel, so I had to transform request to send `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead, and I had to put a function which serializes data in that format. Why isn't this by default?

Another problem is the PUT method, this time in Laravel. I found out that Laravel RESTful controllers don't support PUT methods. Instead, I should send POST request and include `_method: 'PUT'` as a parameter. Here is the improvised code:

```
factory('User',function($resource){
    return $resource(apiPath + 'user/:id', {}, {
        update: {
            method: 'POST', 
            params: {id: '@id'}, 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
            transformRequest: transform()
        }
    })
}
```

Now if I want to send a PUT request, I have to do something like this:

```
var userData = {id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
userData._method = 'PUT';
User.update(userData);
```

So instead of setting `_method` to `'PUT'` each time manually when I want to make a PUT request, is there any way to make it default?
Or, am I doing something wrong, is there a better way to do this? I really don't understand the whole REST thing, what's the point if it's not well supported (Laravel)?. Twitter API also only uses POST and GET. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: In your resource definition set `method: 'PUT'`

Comment: @Chandermani I know about that, but I must send POST requests with parameter _method: 'PUT' so Laravel could read it.

Comment: Look at $http interceptors, they can intercept request and augment the data part using the `config` object. Else create a model class (function) that has this value available and always send such a class.

Comment: Does this work? `User.update({method:'PUT'})` or `User.$update({method:'PUT'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
update: {
    method: 'POST', 
    params: {id: '@id'}, 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(data){
        data._method = 'PUT';
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it just appends it to URL like a GET parameter

Answer (score 0):

Only this method worked for me...

```
'update': {
                    url:  'urlTOApi/product/:id' + '?_method=PUT',
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {id: '@id'},
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                },
```